# How to link to a nested route in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an AngularJS background, and started to play around with React. I'm using the [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) and want have basically this setup:

**Template**

```
export default ( props ) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      { props.children }
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Routing in App.js**

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={Template}>
   <IndexRoute component={RestaurantRoulette} />
    <Route name="workspace" path="workspace(/:workspace_id)" component={RestaurantRoulette}>
      <Route name="run" path="run" component={Run}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

**Navbar**

```
<ul className="navigation">
  <li>RestaurantRoulette</li>
  <Link to="run">Run</Link>
  <li>Save</li>
</ul>
```

### What I want

When I am in `localhost:8080/workspaces/444` I want to click on the `Run` Link, and navigate to `localhost:8080/workspaces/444/run`

### What is the current status

If I manually type the url `localhost:8080/workspaces/444/run`, everything works fine. But when I click on the Link in the navbar, I get to `localhost:8080/run`.

**Can somebody tell me how this works? How this is all connected?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Link tag should be like that:

```
<Link to={'workspaces/' + this.props.workspace_id + '/run'}>Run</link>
```

you should get the workspace_id from path in Template, and pass it to the NavBar component